# Custom layout not showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to make a reusable header. Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonforheader"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        />

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonforheader"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/forward_button"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I made a class for it:

```
public class Header extends RelativeLayout {
    Context context;
    Activity activity;

    public Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        LayoutInflater li  = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        li.inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
    }
}
```

And then added this layout into my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <my.testy.view.Header
        android:id="@+id/headerOnMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </my.testy.view.Header>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerOnMain"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it's not showing up on the application.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attached your inflated layout to your custom class:

```
li.inflate(R.layout.header, this, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I can't believe i forgot this. It has been killing me for hours!

Comment: @Prometheus87 Also I don't see your entire `R.layout.header`, but have a look at this article(if you didn't do it already) -> http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html